Vite / Vue build - Browser does not update index.html
I'm not new to the web and webapp world, I know about browser caching policies and all that but I still don't understand.
I have a WebApp based on its VueJS + VITE fully functional and when I run an update, VITE automatically handles the management of file versions and their names, changing each 'compiled' file name from time to time (I know they are not compiled :) ), the problem is the following:
when I start the page in a browser that has opened it before, on the first load it shows me the old version of the webapp and on the first reload it updates it, I thought it was due precisely to the nomenclature of the [ js + css ] files imported into the html file, but no, I went to look and the actual error is that it doesn't change me these damn browsers don't update the index.html file.
I can yes reload and the page works correctly, but if I close the tab and open another one with the same browser the problem recurs.
I have tried putting the meta tag in the index.html file to remove the caching, but rightly so if it doesn't load the new index.html file for me, this doesn't go :)
Ok to delete browsing data in browsers, but honestly it is a procedure that for a distributed webapp does not seem appropriate.
Does anyone know of any solutions?
P.S. could it be due to the fact that I have a manifest.json file? (I use it to make the webapp fullscreen)
Could it be due to the fact that I use URL-Rewriter and ARR in Microsoft IIS?
I'LL always prefer native apps
